# Is it valid to use conditional expressions for side effects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out what the best way of doing this is:

```
resource['contents'][media_type] = []
resource['contents'][media_type].append(row[0].toPython()) if row[0] is not None else None
resource['contents'][media_type].append(row[2].toPython()) if row[2] is not None else None
```

I think the code is quite simple; if the rows have a value then add them to the list. Is this approach considered OK? Is there any other approach that would be better? The `toPython` method will return the string description of the contained object.

Comment: No, that's not considered OK. Using a ternary for side effects is a really weird approach, making the code harder to read (and giving you very long lines).

Comment: you want to add if value is available if the value is not available what you want to do

Comment: @VigneshKalai nothing if its not available I simply do not add something

Comment: @Giannis why not use a normal conditional operator instead of ternary operator

Comment: @jonrsharpe I believe the wrong part of the code is using an expression for its side effects. It's the same thing as the old `map(side_effectful_function, range(10))` instead of `for i in range(10): side_effectful_function(i)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using a "ternary" [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (`x if C else y`) for side effects is not at all Pythonic. Here's how I would do it:

```
resource['contents'][media_type] = []
for index in (0, 2):
    item = row[i]
    if item is not None:
        resource['contents'][media_type].append(item.toPython())
```

or using a list comprehension to reduce verbosity:

```
resource['contents'][media_type] = [row[i].toPython() for i in (0, 2) 
                                    if row[i] is not None]
```

These approaches are much more readable, and reduce duplication.

Comment: Always forget about list comprehension. Thank you

Comment: Also, is it suggested that I include `is not None` ? Coming from groovy I usually omit that

Comment: @Giannis yes, it is; see the second bullet point at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: I think `for item in (row[0], row[2]):` would be a bit clearer.

Comment: @jpmc26 that's fair enough; I felt it was a bit more repetitive, and note that you could then parameterize the indices (which you can't do with `row[0], row[2]`).

Comment: @Giannis You can **iff** you don't expect `row[i]` to contain other valid falsy values. For example: if `row[i]` could be `0` then using `if row[i]` would result false for both `0` and `None` which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 10):

No, that's not a valid use of a conditional expression. It confuses anyone trying to read your code.

Use an `if` statement; you can save some space by creating another reference to the list:

```
lst = resource['contents'][media_type] = []
if row[0] is not None: lst.append(row[0].toPython()) 
if row[2] is not None: lst.append(row[2].toPython())
```

but use a better name for the local reference (`contents` perhaps?), or use a list comprehension:

```
resource['contents'][media_type] = [
    col.toPython() for col in (row[0], row[2]) if col is not None]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is considered good practice to do that. What you could do instead is:

```
resource['contents'][media_type] = []

for irow in [0, 2]:
    if row[irow] is not None:
        resource['contents'][media_type].append(row[irow].toPython())
```

This allows you the flexibility of also using ranges (for irow in `range(5)`), or using rows if you can access them directly (`for row in rows:`).

Comment: How does this add to the two existing answers?

Comment: I had the post open before there were any responses. At the time, there were only two comments below the OP. I think your answer was correct.

Comment: What browser are you using? Anything relatively modern will show you a banner when answers are added or edited.

Comment: I am using Chrome. Do they appear if you are in another tab? How long do they stay up? Do they appear if you are scrolled down? Are the banners affected by adblock? I do not recall seeing any, but I'll keep an eye out from now on.

Comment: I don't think so; I use AdBlock, and they appear for me. The new answer banner appears at the top of the answers section (which will be immediately above your answer if you started when there weren't any), the edited answer banner appears at the top of the answer in question.